# Logic and set theory (De Morgan's law)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have to prove, that $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$, for sets $A$, $B$, $C$ and $A, B \subset C$. And my friend prove it this way:

$$ x \in (A \cap B)^c \Leftrightarrow x \in (A \land B)^c \Leftrightarrow x \not\in (A \land B) \Leftrightarrow (x \not\in A) \lor (x \not\in B) \Leftrightarrow x \in (A^c \cup B^c)$$

Is it right? I have thought, that you cannot use $\lor$, $\land$ for sets. But he said, that this operation are define for sets too.

I don't need help to prove the De Morgan's law, but can you explain me, how are define $\land$ ans $\lor$ for sets?

Comment: What do the operators $\land$, $\lor$ identify in your usual notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your friend is wrong. $\land$ and $\lor$ are for logical formulas, not for sets. However, there is a strong connection between these and $\cap$ and $\cup$, as follows.
$$x \in A \cap B \iff x \in A \land x \in B$$
and
$$x \in A \cup B \iff x \in A \lor x \in B.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are logical connnectors they cannot be used for sets such as A and B. As you see,your friend uses them as $\cap$ and $\cup$ finally,so why intoduce such an equivalt notation? It is true that DeMorgan laws have their corresponding version in logic,but the thing you should write up there is :
$$(x\notin A) \vee (x \notin  B)
$$ from the fourth passage,because it sound like "x doesn't belong to A AND (=$\vee$,logical connector) x doesn't belong to B".Try replacing $\vee$ with $\cup$ and $\wedge$ with $\cap$ in the passages before and you'll see you'll get the same meaning(even though $A \vee B$ has no meaning for sets).